# jQuery :contains() selector is not working IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, internet-explorer, jquery-selectors

I am using the jQuery :contains() selector to display only items from my XML file that contain a specific text string. It works perfectly in FF, Safari, Chrome etc etc, but not in IE7, 8 or 9. Any ideas?

`jQuery(RSSqa).find("item:contains('Q & A with'):lt(1)").each(function(){`

This bit of code displays the latest item in a XML with "Q & A with" in it.

Here is some of the RSS feed

```
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>Headlines</title>
<link>Coyotes</link>
<description>Coyotes</description>
<lastBuildDate>Fri, 17 Jun 2011 16:54:44 EDT</lastBuildDate>
<item>
<title>Q &amp; A with Brandon</title>
<enclosure length="63471" type="image/png" url="http://google.com/images/upload/325.jpg"></enclosure><link>http://google.com/news.htm?id=56362</link>
<description>description</description>
<author>Dave</author>
<pubDate>Tue, 24 May 2011 09:58:00 EDT</pubDate>
<guid>http://google.com/news.htm?id=56362</guid>
<comments>Brandon is a winner</comments>
</item>
<item>
<title>Q &amp; A with Jason</title>
<enclosure length="63471" type="image/png" url="http://google.com/images/upload/323.jpg"></enclosure><link>http://google.com/news.htm?id=56363</link>
<description>description</description>
<author>Dave</author>
<pubDate>Tue, 24 May 2011 09:58:00 EDT</pubDate>
<guid>http://google.com/news.htm?id=56363</guid>
<comments>Brandon is a winner</comments>
</item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

And here is the entire script. I hope this helps.

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function()
                  {

    jQuery.get('news.xml', function(RSSqa){ // NEWS XML

    jQuery('#nrmr2.colModRight .DCnarModBody').append('<div class="DCnarModR" />');

    jQuery(RSSqa).find("item:contains('Q & A with'):lt(1)").each(function(){ 

                        var headline = jQuery(this);
                    var $enclosure = headline.find('enclosure');
                    var image = $enclosure.attr("url");
                        var headlinesTitle = headline.find('title').text();
                    var link = headline.find('guid').text();
                        var description = headline.find('description').text();
                        var teaser = headline.find('comments').text();
                        var author = headline.find("author").text();
                    var pubDate = headline.find("pubDate").text();

var qaData = '<img src="' + image +'" height="172px" width="306px" >';                      
    qaData += '<a href="' + link + '" > <h1> ' + headlinesTitle + '</h1></a>';
    qaData += '' + teaser + ' <br clear="all" />';
    qaData += '<a href="' + link + '" class="mainButton" ><span>FULL STORY &rsaquo;</span></a>';
    jQuery('div.DCnarModR').append(jQuery(qaData));
    });
    });         
    });
```

Comment: [Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/F39kE/1).

Comment: could it be that the `&` needs to be escaped, or referenced as `&amp;` ?

Comment: @jnpcl: jQuery handles entities properly as demonstrated in my fiddle.

Comment: Maybe we need to see some of this XML you've got.

Comment: @BoltClock Your jsfiddle does not work in IE. I opened the http://jsfiddle.net/F39kE/1/ and there are no results shown in IE.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this as well.  It seems, for whatever reason, that jQuery will only perform its standard traversal functions on an actual XML object in Internet Explorer.

The workaround I used was to use some simple feature detection to see first if you are in IE, then to transform your XML string into an XML object for jQuery to use.

Something like:

```
function Convert(xmlStr) {
    if (window.ActiveXObject && (new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM") != null)) {
        var xd = new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        if (xd) {
            xd.loadXML(xmlStr);
            return xd;
        }
    }
    return xmlStr;
}
```

Then, in your code (I tried this with your example RSS and it seems to do the trick in IE8).

```
jQuery.get('news.xml', function(RSSqa) { // NEWS XML
    RSSqa = Convert(RSSqa);
    jQuery(RSSqa).find("item:contains('Q & A with'):lt(1)").each(function() { 
        /* rest of your code... */
    });
});
```

Hope that helps!